# How can I add custom columns inside Jira issue List View programatically?

Tags: java, maven, jira-plugin

[image]

I have to add a column in the Jira Issue List view programatically. Or I want to append data to the "**Summary**" column?. Please refer the attached image for better understanding

Comment: Why do you need to do it programmatically? You could just create a custom field containing the data you want to display and use the "Columns" button on the right side of the issue list you see to add it to the list. Then just drag the column to the position you want it to be in.

Comment: I want to create a Jira Plugin. I have to show some data related to that plugin in a column.

Comment: You'd probably need a web panel plugin module but I don't know what the location would be. If you have the JIRA source code, you could try running a find `$ find path/to/jira/src -name atlassian-plugin.xml | xargs grep 'web-panel.*location'` which will search for atlassian-plugin.xml's in JIRA src code and find different web panel locations for you to try.

Comment: From what I can see, the Velocity template for this can be found in the JIRA source code at `/WEB-INF/classes/templates/jira/issue/table`. The macros.vm template has most of the code in it. The classes you may want to look at to add a column are in the package `com.atlassian.jira.issue.fields.layout.column`, specifically the EditableDefaultColumnLayout (has an addColumn method) and the ColumnLayoutManager (to get an instance of the previously mentioned class) may be useful.